# Laravel 3 - Passing variables across multiple views

Tags: variables, post, view, laravel

I have two forms on two different views. I would like to post the form input to the second view, and then back to the first form upon posting the second form.

I have set up a test with a route that looks like this :

```
Route::get('/test1', function() {
    return View::make('test1');
});

Route::post('/test2', function() {
    $flash = Input::get();
    return View::make('test2')->with('flash', $flash);
});

Route::post('/test1', function() {
    return View::make('test1')->with('flash', $flash);
});
```

I am only able to pass `$flash` once. I'm misunderstanding why I cannot pass it again. I feel like I have to extract it again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a form field in `/test2` and resubmit the $flash data in order to pass it to `/test1` via POST. It's a new request, the app will lose the $flash var otherwise.

A different approach could be to store $flash in a session with `Session::put('flash', $flash);` and accessing it in the next request.

Answer (score 2):

The best method is to store your data in session. It will be available across multiple request . Using Input::flash() will only be available until the next request. See the Laravel docs for [Input::flash()](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#old-input) and [Session](http://laravel.com/docs/session)